Purge all commit history from GitHub Repository
I have a number of private github repositories that I want to transfer to a new owner.  As part of the transfer, I want to wipe all the history to ensure that no sensitive artifacts remain in version history.
Through googling and ChatGpt, I've found and run the following commands:
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
git add -A
git commit -am "Initial commit"
git branch -D main
git branch -m main
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push -f origin main

and
rmdir -r .git
git init -b main
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/XXXXX/YYYYY
git push --prune --force --set-upstream origin main

The commands only seem to clean up the commit history in GitHub.
A URL like:
https://github.com/XXXXX/YYYYY/commits/main/
shows only shows one entry (which is what I want), HOWEVER, if I go to a URL like:
https://github.com/XXXXX/YYYYY/tree/c7acde7462c9052256942603ee2a1be08bf8bab3
I am still able to see the data from an old commit.
(GitHub does show the following message:  This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.)
How do I remove all history so that a URL like:
https://github.com/XXXXX/YYYYY/tree/c7acde7462c9052256942603ee2a1be08bf8bab3
no longer works and any data not stored in my "reset commit" is purged?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758 "If you pushed to GitHub, force pushing is not enough, delete the repository or contact support" Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remove+sensitive+files

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github - but note "GitHub Support won't remove non-sensitive data, and will only assist in the removal of sensitive data in cases where we determine that the risk can't be mitigated by rotating affected credentials."

Your problem is that although your commands (either your first option of creating an orphan branch and pushing an initial commit, or just deleting the Git repository and creating it afresh) delete the history in git, they don’t delete it in GitHub. GitHub (the website) stores, independently of Git (the version-control system), the previous forks and branches that are no longer part of the repository.
If you look at your https://github.com/XXXXX/YYYYY/tree/c7acde... link, you'll notice a message at the top of the GitHub page saying “This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository”. This is because the commit is stored by GitHub, but isn't part of your Git repository.
Solution 1: New repository — As far as I know there isn’t any way of manually deleting permanently a Git commit from a GitHub repo, even after it’s been deleted from Git. Your only way of truly purging all history from GitHub may be to simply start a new repository, copy all the files, delete your previous one, and rename your new repository.
Solution 2: Waiting — If you’re okay with waiting a while, GitHub does eventually delete unreachable commits and other dangling objects, a process called garbage collection. This process isn’t instantaneous, and (as described in the previous paragraph) there is no way of manually taking control of it, but eventually your deleted commits will be purged from GitHub. The amount of time this takes can differ (depending on whether it’s a public or private repository). However, if your repository includes truly sensitive data (passwords, identifying details, private keys, etc.) go for option 1 — you don’t want to rely on garbage-collection to hide your private data. Deleting the repo is the safest and most reliable way of ensuring sensitive information doesn’t leak.
